# INotifyPropertyChanged, no UI updates

Tags: silverlight, inotifypropertychanged

I looked around the web for an answer, but can't seem to get this to work. Here is what I have:

```
public class UIValues : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private double zoomValue = 1;

        private static readonly UIValues instance = new UIValues();

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        internal static UIValues Instance { get { return instance; } }

        internal double ZoomValue
        {
            get { return zoomValue; }
            set
            {
                if (this.zoomValue == value)
                    return;

                this.zoomValue = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ZoomValue"));
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
```

and then I have this:

```
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
            <local:UIValues x:Name="uiValues"/>
        </UserControl.DataContext>

.
.
.

                <Viewbox x:Name="vbViewBox" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                    <local:ImageControl x:Name="imgControl" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Viewbox.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                    <CompositeTransform x:Name="trCompositeTransform" ScaleX="{Binding ZoomValue}" ScaleY="{Binding ZoomValue}" Rotation="0" SkewX="0" SkewY="0"/>
                            </TransformGroup>
                    </Viewbox.RenderTransform>
                </Viewbox>
</UserControl>
```

So basically, whenever I make a change to the ZoomValue from the UIValues class from code-behind, the UI is not updated.

Anyone know why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change access modifier for `ZoomValue` property to public and everything will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the posted code I'll have a guess that you have something like this to change the Zoom Value.

```
  UIValues.Instance.ZoomValue = x;
```

The problem is this xaml:-

```
  <local:UIValues x:Name="uiValues"/>
```

constructs an independent instance of UIValues that is not the same instance returned by your static `Instance` property.  Hence you will be changing a value on a object that nothing is listening to.

**Edit**

Also ZoomLevel is `internal`, for it work with binding is must be public.

The solution is to use `IApplicationService` and do things through App.xaml.

Change you class to:

```
public class UIValues : INotifyPropertyChanged,  IApplicationService
{
    private double zoomValue = 1;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    internal static UIValues Instance { get; private set; }

    public double ZoomValue
    {
        get { return zoomValue; }
        set
        {
            if (zoomValue == value)
                return;

            zoomValue = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ZoomValue"));
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, e);
    }

    void IApplicationService.StartService(ApplicationServiceContext context)
    {
        Instance = this;
        Application.Current.Resources.Add("UIValues", Instance);
    }

    void IApplicationService.StopService() { }
}
```

Add the instance of `UIValues` to App.Xaml:-

```
<Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
    <local:UIValues />
</Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
```

Then set the user control `DataContext` like this:-

```
<UserControl ... DataContext="{StaticResource UIValues}">
```

That said this is waste of the `DataContext` which you may need to bind to real data.  You can specify the `Source` directly on the bindings instead:-

```
 <CompositeTransform ScaleX="{Binding ZoomValue, Source={StaticResource UIValues}}" ScaleY="{Binding ZoomValue, Source={StaticResource UIValues}}" Rotation="0" SkewX="0" SkewY="0"/>
```